# How do I use multiple npm registries in Yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to setup Yarn 0.17.9 in our environment but I have a problem with our registry. We are currently using two registries, official npmjs and our own registry on internal network (Sinopia).

The problem is that we are using internal tool to pull packages from one or the other with --registry flag via `npm install`. `yarn add` doesn't have --registry option and I'm unable to set the custom registry globally with fallback to npmjs. I tried `.npmrc` but it sets only one registry for npm/yarn in project. `.yarnrc` doesn't seem to work and is silenced by `.npmrc`

Is there any way to specify two registries (fallback to second registry if the package is not found in the first one)? Or specify different npm registry per package?

Answer (score 9):

You can make a `.yarnrc` file in the root of the project and write this line in that file:

```
registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

This will act as a project specific repository.

Comment: What about multiple registries?

Answer (score 9):

For anyone finding this in 2021, yarn now [can work with **scopes**, private registries and auth](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/839).

For example, I have published private packages such as `@my-company-private-scope/my-package` to a [Verdaccio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verdaccio) (fork of [Sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia)) server and my `.npmrc` configuration is like:

```
; Lines starting with ; are for .npmrc file comments
; yarn 1.22.10 seems to default registry to https://registry.yarnpkg.com
; no matter what I put here /shrug
; registry=https://registry.npmjs.com/

@my-company-private-scope:registry=https://npm.my-company.com/
//npm.my-company.com/:_authToken=TOKEN

; I did not seem to need this, as
; yarn still installed public and private packages successfully
; based on what ended up in my yarn.lock file
; //npm.my-company.com/:always-auth true
```

It looks like [npm also supports scopes](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry), in that while `yarn unpublish` doesn't exist, `npm unpublish @my-company-private-scope/my-package@1.0.1-5` also worked beautifully.

I don't have a need to try multiple scopes on multiple private servers yet (though [might](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry)), however I also don't see any good reason it wouldn't work beautifully too.

Answer (score 7):

Yarn doesn't have support --registry flag as npm but you can set up your registry in .yarnrc

If your .yarnrc is being ignored it can be copied out of the ~/.yarnrc using:

```
yarn config set registry http://registry.com/registry//
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to set up two registries, one for our internal server and one for registry.npmjs.org. I tried to list config of yarn and the registry is set on our internal server and under npm info the registry is npmjs.org. However when i try `yarn add internalpackage` yarn tries npmjs.org and fails.

Comment: @kraklin the way hosted repositories like Gemfury solves this is by proxying all requests for repos that does not exist in the private space to `https://registry.npmjs.org/`. You could do something similar

Comment: @hamohl Yes, we tried it with our Sinopia, unfortunately this setup did not work in our network so we switched off the proxy option and keep the custom setup with two registries.

Comment: @Andres it support registry tag for specific project.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying in my answer but it's not a flag and it doesn't help to use npm as a fallback registry.

Comment: Maybe nexus's [Grouping npm Registries](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/node-packaged-modules-and-npm-registries#NodePackagedModulesandnpmRegistries-GroupingnpmRegistries) can help

Answer (score 5):

You can try set different registry in `.npmrc` and `.yarnrc`.

So for example:
In `.npmrc`:

```
registry=https://yourcompany/
virtual/:_authToken=credentials
always-auth=true
```

always-auth=true **needs to be the very last line in the file**

And in `.yarnrc`:

```
registry "https://registry.yarnpkg.com"
```

Then `yarn add`/`npm install` + private-pakage/public-packge will work.

Comment: Still not sure why it's working through but at least this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As for version 3 (3.4.1), You can define multiple repositories by putting such config in .yarnrc.yml file (example of GitHub Packages):

```
npmScopes: 
  your-organization-or-account:
    npmRegistryServer: "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
```

For more options - Yarn docs reference (search for 'npmScopes'): [yarn-docs](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc)

Edit:

It also works same way for version 4 (4.0.2 currently).