# How to set registry for namespaced package with yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, sinopia

I am giving `yarn` a try as a replacement for `npm`.

For npm, we use both a private sinopia registry and for some namespaced package the official repoistory as well, as sinopia doesn't handle the namespace.

Since my `.npmrc` has these registries defined.

```
registry=http://sinopia-registry.internal:4873/
@types:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

I know that I can set the registry globally in `yarn` in its `.yarnrc` via:

```
registry "http://sinopia-registry.internal:4873/"
```

Yet how to I tell yarn to use a different registry form `@types` namespaced packages?

I tried different approaches on the lines of:

```
registry @types "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

Yet they all lead to yarn to complain about syntax errors.

Comment: Doh. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845598/how-do-i-use-multiple-npm-registries-in-yarn

Answer (score 1):

Try instead using:

```
"@types:registry" "https://registry.npmjs.org"
```